# Using Caffe in Qt Console Application

Tags: c++, qt, caffe

I am trying to use caffe in Qt IDE,

I have the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"

using namespace caffe;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I just wanted to set Caffe in CPU Mode.

I have the following .pro file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = CaffeTest_v0
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /home/ahmet/caffe/include \
               /home/ahmet/caffe/distribute/include \
               /home/ahmet/caffe/build/lib

 LIBS += -lcaffe

 SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I have the following problem :

[image]

My problem is I want to set caffe in CPU mode, I installed caffe in CPU mode.

How can I set Caffe in CPU mode in main?

P.S. I believe I installed caffe corectly, because I tested by the following command in gnome terminal

```
caffe train -solver lenet_train_solver.prototxt
```

I also searched the following websites:

- http://tzutalin.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/caffe-on-ubuntu-eclipse-cc.html
- [Error while including Caffe in C++ Project using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760895/error-while-including-caffe-in-c-project-using-cmake)
- https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3317
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/DAv5EcsvbIU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .pro file, I should add

```
DEFINES += CPU_ONLY
```

solves the problem.

Final .pro file is below:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = CaffeTest_v0
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += CPU_ONLY



INCLUDEPATH += /home/ahmet/caffe/include \
           /home/ahmet/src/caffe/proto \
           /usr/include/boost

LIBS += -L/home/ahmet/caffe/build/lib \
        -lcaffe \
        -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
        -lboost_system


SOURCES += main.cpp
```